# Не могу найти указатель

Tags: курсор, c++

Мне в программе нужен вот такой указатель:

[image]

Пол часа его ищу и не могу найти. Откуда его можно загрузить?

ОС - `Windows 7`,
`API` - `Win32`.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы имеете ввиду загрузку курсора в свое приложение посредством функции LoadCursor, LoadStandardCursor и т.д, то вот список констант курсоров, которые существуют:

```
IDC_ARROW - Стандартный курсор стрелки
IDC_IBEAM - Стандартный курсор вставки текста
IDC_WAIT - Используемый курсор Песочных часов, когда Windows выполняет отнимающую много времени задачу.
IDC_CROSS - Курсор Перекрестия для выделения
IDC_UPARROW - Стрелка, которая указывает прямо
IDC_SIZE - Устаревший и неподдерживаемый. Используйте IDC_SIZEALL
IDC_SIZEALL - Стрелка с четырьмя указателями. Курсор используеться чтобы изменить размеры окна.
IDC_ICON - Устаревший и неподдерживаемый. Используйте IDC_ARROW.
IDC_SIZENWSE - Стрелка с двумя указателями на верхнем левом и более низком правом.
IDC_SIZENESW - Стрелка с двумя указателями с концами на верхнем правом и нижнем левом
IDC_SIZEWE - Горизонтальная стрелка с двумя указателями
IDC_SIZENS - Вертикальная стрелка с двумя указателями
```